# Marking KnownFailures in Selenium Cucumber-JVM report

Tags: automation, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, cucumber-java

We are currently working on a spike to - start marking/highlighting known failures in tests ran using Cucumber-JVM [Java selenium environment].
We currently use Masterthought plugin on top of standard Cucumber generated reports [ But will be open for any other open-source plugin or rely on standard Cucumber (JSON/JavaScript/XML/HTML) report ]

( This will be something similar to team city's Mute facility but rather a bespoke solution )

1. We are planning to maintain our own small dB or properties file, which will contain test case reference of known failures
2. From next test run onwards, I want my Cucumber test report to highlight or at least have a some sort of column / flag in the report which could highlight about a Known failures (from above referred mapping in Step-1), if same test case fails again.

Could you please share any thoughts on how to implement this Known failure functionality?

How can we manipulate Cucumber runner & output?

If we manage to change the Cucumber output for example - JSON / XML output file, then will any external reporting plugin like- MasterThought be able to pick up the change.

Kindly provide your valuable experience on any similar effort.

Many thanks

Comment: Hey guys, any update on this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QAF BDD](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/scenario.html) where in scenario meta-data you can specify additional meta-data, let say defect-id. For example below is method invocation listener implementation:

```
SCENARIO: Example test
META-DATA: {"description":"Data driven test that uses csv file to provide data", "defect-id":"PRJ-123"}
    Given I am on fruits and colors activity
    When i select '${fruit}'
    Then the color should be '${color}'
END
```

You can use Standard TestNG listeners to further process after test complete. You will be able to access your custom meta data in listener. For example:

```
@Override
public void afterInvocation(final IInvokedMethod method, final ITestResult tr, final ITestContext context) {

    if (method.isTestMethod()) {
        TestNGScenario scenario = (TestNGScenario) tr.getMethod();
        Map<String, Object> metadata =scenario.getMetaData();
        if(metadata.containsKey("defect-id")){
        //do the needful
        }
    }
}
```